# How to move object using socket.io in html 5 Multiplayer game

Tags: node.js, socket.io

im trying to build a multiplayer card game using Quintus HTML5 game engine and node.js and socket.io till now i have create mainLevel scene and insert some card objects into this scene and the cards can be touch by mose and drag when the player let go the card it go to center of the screen and to make this game multiplayer game i use socket.io to do that but i'm litle bit lost there is no any documentation or resources on how to build game with socket.io but so what i did now with socket when new client go to the index page of the game he is connect automatically to room called Lobby and when card played (moved) all other player in this room know that a card is move but i cant actually figure out how to move the card that one player has played in the other playeres scene.

so what i do till now is :

server.js:

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//_______________________________________________

app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

//_______________________________________________

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '...');
//_______________________________________________

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('a user connected\n');//log test

//on socket connection serever add user to lobby room   
 socket.on('adduser', function() {
        socket.room = 'Lobby';//set the socket.room to Lobby room when first connect by Defults
        socket.join('Lobby');//let the client sockt join the Lobby room by Defult when firts connect to server 
    });

socket.on('tellothers', function(data) {
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('cardmove', data);
    });
});
```

game.js:

```
var Q = window.Q = Quintus().include("Sprites, Scenes, Input, Touch");
Q.setup("myGame").touch(Q.SPRITE_ALL);

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect',function(){
  console.log('user connect');
});

socket.emit('adduser');

socket.on('cardmove',function(data){
   console.log('Card Name : '+ data.cardName + ' x :' + data.x + ' y : ' + data.y);
});

//Define Card object
Q.Sprite.extend("Card", {

    init: function (p) {

        this._super(p)

        this.on("drag");
        this.on("touchEnd");

    },

    drag: function (touch) {    

        this.p.dragging = true;
        this.p.x = touch.origX + touch.dx;
        this.p.y = touch.origY + touch.dy;

    },

    touchEnd: function (touch) {

        // put a line on the screen if the card pass it put the card in the new position if not put the card in the orginal(old) postion 
        if (touch.origY + touch.dy > touch.origY - ((10/100)*Q.el.height)) { //define the line that the card should pass if the amount of draged > the screen line in Q.el.height - 200

            // put the card in the same old postion if is not pass the line
            this.p.x = touch.origX;
            this.p.y = touch.origY;

        } else {
            // put the card if it pass the line in the new postion  
            this.p.x = ((50/100)*Q.el.width);
            this.p.y = Q.el.height - ((50/100)*Q.el.height);
            //end the drag and touch after one time the object has been draged 

            touch.obj.off('drag'); 
            touch.obj.off('touchEnd');

            socket.emit('tellothers',{cardName: this.p.name ,x: this.p.x , y: this.p.y});
        }
    },
});

//___________________________________________________________________

//drwa objects in canvace
Q.scene("mainLevel", function(stage){
    Q.gravity = 0;
    stage.insert(new Q.Sprite({ asset: "Card_Table.png", x:Q.el.width / 2, y: Q.el.height / 2, type: Q.SPRITE_NON }));

  stage.insert(new Q.Card({name:'Card_1',asset: "Queen_OF_Hearts.png", scale: 0.60, x: Q.el.width / 2, y: Q.el.height - ((15/100)*Q.el.height) }));

  stage.insert(new Q.Card({name:'Card_2',asset:'Queen_OF_Hearts.png', scale: 0.50, x: ((20/100)*Q.el.width), y: Q.el.height - ((50/100)*Q.el.height)}));

  stage.insert(new Q.Card({name:'Card_3',asset:'Queen_OF_Hearts.png', scale: 0.80, x: ((80/100)*Q.el.width), y: Q.el.height - ((50/100)*Q.el.height)}));

  stage.insert(new Q.Card({name:'Card_4',asset:'Queen_OF_Hearts.png', x: ((50/100)*Q.el.width), y: Q.el.height - ((80/100)*Q.el.height)}));

});

 //___________________________________________________________________

Q.debug = true;
Q.debugFill = true;

//load assets
Q.load(["Card_Table.png","Queen_OF_Hearts.png"], function(){
    Q.stageScene("mainLevel");
});

 //___________________________________________________________________

var currentObj = null;

     Q.el.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e) {
        var x = e.offsetX || e.layerX,
            y = e.offsetY || e.layerY,
            stage = Q.stage();

        var stageX = Q.canvasToStageX(x, stage),
            stageY = Q.canvasToStageY(y, stage);

        var obj = stage.locate(stageX,stageY);

        if(currentObj) { currentObj.p.over = false; }
            if(obj) {
              currentObj = obj;
              obj.p.over = true;
            }
  });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Card Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>  
    <canvas id='myGame' width= "640" height="603" class="img-responsive"></canvas>
    <script src="/JS/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/JS/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/JS/quintus-all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/JS/Game.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

so please any help on how to make the card that one player play move to in the other players in the game.

**UPDATE:**:

new [link to download source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tlsfysd38m7mkqh/CardGameV6.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have succeeded in moving the same object in all the connected user in the game so what i did

First:
i add array of objects `var cards = [];` empty by default for later use to put(push) all the card into it and for update the object that is moved.

Second:
i change the 

`socket.emit('tellothers',{cardName: this.p.name ,x: this.p.x , y: this.p.y});`
to
`socket.emit('tellothers',{cardName:this.p.name, cardAsset:this.p.asset, cardScale:this.p.scale, cardX:this.p.x, cardY:this.p.y});` 
i pass all the parameters of the moveded card for later use to let know the other client what is the card that have been moved.

Third:
then in the mainLevel scene after the card are inserted i have push all the card to the `var cards = [];`

```
cards.push({name:'Card_1',asset: "Queen_OF_Hearts.png", scale: 0.60, x: Q.el.width / 2, y: Q.el.height - ((15/100)*Q.el.height) });
cards.push({name:'Card_2',asset:'Queen_OF_Hearts.png', scale: 0.50, x: ((20/100)*Q.el.width), y: Q.el.height - ((50/100)*Q.el.height)});
cards.push({name:'Card_3',asset:'Queen_OF_Hearts.png', scale: 0.80, x: ((80/100)*Q.el.width), y: Q.el.height - ((50/100)*Q.el.height)});
cards.push({name:'Card_4',asset:'Queen_OF_Hearts.png', scale:0.00 ,x: ((50/100)*Q.el.width), y: Q.el.height - ((80/100)*Q.el.height)});
```

Fourth:
i have create new `updateLevel` scene for later use in updating the scenes of all client with the card that has been move in all client even the scene of the client that move the card.

```
Q.scene("updateLevel", function(stage){
  Q.gravity = 0;

  stage.insert(new Q.Sprite({ asset: "Card_Table.png", x:Q.el.width / 2, y: Q.el.height / 2, type: Q.SPRITE_NON }));

  for(sub in cards){
    stage.insert(new Q.Card({name:cards[sub].name, asset:cards[sub].asset, scale:cards[sub].scale, x:cards[sub].x, y:cards[sub].y}));
  }

});
```

Fifth:
i create some function for calling him in late time when scene has been update

```
var UpdateCards = function(){
    Q.clearStages();
    Q.stageScene('updateLevel');
}
```

then:
when `cardmove`

```
  socket.on('cardmove',function(data){

     data.cardX = ((50/100)*Q.el.width);
     data.cardY = Q.el.height - ((50/100)*Q.el.height);

  cards = cards.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.name !== data.cardName;
});

  cards.push({name:data.cardName, asset:data.cardAsset, scale:data.cardScale, x:data.cardX, y:data.cardY});

  UpdateCards();
});
```

and in the server side:
i change

```
socket.on('tellothers', function(data) {
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('cardmove', data);
    });
```

to

```
socket.on('tellothers', function(data) {
        io.sockets["in"](socket.room).emit('cardmove', data);
    });
```

i update the question and put the new source code and link for download it if you want the try it :D.